# Is there anyway fsi.exe can be made to run on .NET 3.5?

Tags: f#

I am have managed to get fsi.exe become 64 bit... next I want it to load/work with .NET 3.5. Has anyone figured out a way to do this?

I have found some dated blog entries regarding this ... but no solution.

since there is no way to support older version. I get following error If I try to load .NET 3.5 DLLs into FSI

```
> let s = new SPSite("http://myserver/sites/test");;
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Microsoft SharePoint is not supported 
with version 4.0.30319.269 of the Microsoft .Net
Runtime.
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.get_Farm()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.FindLocal(SPFarm& farm, Boolean& isJoined)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(String requestUrl)
at <StartupCode$FSI_0005>.$FSI_0005.main@()
Stopped due to error
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FSI references .NET 4, so it's not possible to run it on an older version of the CLR.  SharePoint is an exception to the rule - usually one *can* load assemblies which reference older .NET versions.  There must have been some compatibility issues that caused the SharePoint team to explicitly disable loading on .NET 4+.  I would not expect such an error to come up for most other .NET 3.5 assemblies you try to load.